# How to evaluate variables and use pre-defined value in echo of code chunk

Tags: r-markdown

I am creating randomized exercises for students using R markdown.
I would like to define some variables in a first non-echoed code chunk and use these variables later on with their pre-defined values echoed in the code chunks instead of their variable names.

Reprex: In a first r markdown code chunk I define:

```r
mu <- 100
sd <- 15
```

In a later r markdown code chunk I would then like to use these previously defined variables and echo the code with the previously defined variable values already evaluated.

```r
pnorm(90, mean = mu, sd = sd)
```

Accordingly, I would like the above code chunk in the knitted document to be echoed as:
pnorm(90, mean = 100, sd = 15)
##  0.2524925

But it echoes as:
pnorm(90, mean = mu, sd = sd)
##  0.2524925

I have already tried using functions such as get(mu) or eval(mu) in the code chunks.
But this only resulted in errors or in the proper result value displayed but with echo being the actual code:
pnorm(90, mean = eval(mu), sd = 15)
##  0.2524925

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by specifying the `code` argument in the chunk options. You would use `substitute()` to put the values into the code, then `knitr` will put that code into the chunk.

For example,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
mu <- 100
sd <- 15
thecode <- substitute(pnorm(90, mean = mu1, sd = sd1),
                      list(mu1 = mu, sd1 = sd))
```

```{r code = thecode}
```
````

A couple of notes:

- You don't need to change the variable names, I just did it to distinguish between the tokens in the expression you were modifying (`mu1` and `sd1`) and the values you were putting in there (`mu` and `sd`).
- The `knitr` format I was using requires you to put the entire list of chunk options on one line.  That's why I stored the code in `thecode`.  If you had a short bit of code that expression `substitute(...)` could be put
  right into the chunk header.  There's also a newer format where chunk options are on separate lines, with `#|` prefixes.  I don't use that much.
- R Markdown allows you to specify parameters when you produce the document, you don't need to hard code the 100 and 15 in the document.  See https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-6.html .

Comment: Works like a charm! 
Thanks for informing be about the substitute() function and the functionality of the "code"chunk option!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to user2554330 for telling me about the substitute() function and the "code" chunk option.
His proposed solution works like a charm.

For ease of implementation I decided, however, to rewrite it with the substitute() function called directly in the code chunk like this:

````
```{r markdowncode, echo = FALSE, comment=NA}
    
substitute(pnorm(90, mean = mu1, sd = sd1), list(mu1 = mu, sd1 = sd))
pnorm(30, mu, sd)

```
````

This in the end results in the following included in the markdown document:

```
pnorm(90, mean = 100, sd = 15)
[1] 0.2524925
```

Comment: I think you left out some important bits.  Can you include the backticks around your code chunk?  You can use 4 backticks on SO to include code that has 3 backticks in it.

Comment: Included the backticks! Didn't know about the trick with 4 backticks. Thanks!